# Completely normal Ubuntu installation from USB stick (completely formatting drive etc.) fails with 'invalid arch-independent ELF magic'

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

After booting into an Ubuntu 20 Live image from a USB stick, I am able to install Ubuntu completely as normal with no indication of any problems, but once the installation finishes and I am invited to remove the boot USB and restart, I get the error 'invalid arch-independent ELF magic'.

Looking online, I have only seen this when people are doing complex dual-boot or multi-partition installs, whereas I am doing what I think is probably the simplest installation possible: only one hard drive which I am formatting completely then installing the latest Ubuntu onto.

I can see that the grub boot files are not in the right place, however them not being present is apparently a symptom of the installation failing somehow so I'd much rather fix the issue.

I've spent about 5 hours trying to solve this so forgive me if it seems like I'm asking about a very simple problem, but how on earth do you persuade the installer to actually add the necessary grub boot files?!

P.S. I watched the log as it installed and the grub install process seemed to go completely normally with no errors.

Comment: Where are the "not in the right place" files? Where do you think they should be? What's your hardware? Can't both "install Ubuntu completely as normal with no indication of any problems" and "grub boot files in the wrong place". What disk partition scheme did you choose?

Comment: Did drive have a previous grub. Error is often from grub version mis-match. Or using old grub to try to boot newer install. UEFI or BIOS installs? Old MBR or newer gpt partitioning? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair